# Search multiple colours simultaneously with opencv and c++

Tags: opencv, image-processing, colors, detection, mask

I am trying to make the code below search multiple colours at the same time e.g. red, yellow and orange. I have added masks to the code but a cant get them to apply properly what am i doing wrong I am not sure if the line to add the masks to the frame is in the right place or not.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace std;

using namespace cv::gpu;



IplImage* GetThresholdedImage(IplImage* imgHSV){       
    IplImage* imgThresh=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgHSV),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(170,160,60), cvScalar(180,255,256), imgThresh); 
    return imgThresh;
} 
int main(){
    //Char Firetype = type;
     CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
     if(!capture){
        printf("Capture failure\n");
        return -1;
    }
    IplImage* frame=0;

    cvNamedWindow("Video");     
    cvNamedWindow("Fire");
    cvNamedWindow("Info");
    //iterate through each frame of the video     
    while(true){
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);           
        if(!frame) break;
        frame=cvCloneImage(frame); 
        cvSmooth(frame, frame, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3); //smooth the original image using Gaussian kernel
        cv::Mat imgMat(frame);
        cv::Mat mask1;
        cv::inRange(imgMat, cv::Scalar(20, 100, 100), cv::Scalar(30, 255, 255), mask1);
        cv::Mat mask2;
        cv::inRange(imgMat, cv::Scalar(170,160,60), cv::Scalar(180,255,256), mask2);
        cv::Mat mask3;
        cv::inRange(imgMat, cv::Scalar(70,160,60), cv::Scalar(90,255,256), mask3);
        // combine them
        cv::Mat mask_combined = mask1 | mask2 | mask3;
        // now since our frame from the camera is bgr, we have to convert our mask to 3 channels:
        cv::Mat mask_rgb;
        cv::cvtColor( mask_combined, mask_rgb, CV_GRAY2BGR );
        IplImage framemask = imgMat & mask_rgb;
        IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(framemask), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3); 
        cvCvtColor(frame, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV); //Change the color format from BGR to HSV


        //This function threshold the HSV image and create a binary image
        // function below to get b&w image
        IplImage* imgThresh = GetThresholdedImage(imgHSV);
        cvSmooth(imgThresh, imgThresh, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3); //smooth the binary image using Gaussian kernel
        cvShowImage("Fire", imgThresh);           
        cvShowImage("Video", frame);
        //          cvNamedWindow("Info", Firetype);           
        cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
        cvReleaseImage(&imgThresh);            
        cvReleaseImage(&frame);
        //Wait 50mS
        int c = cvWaitKey(10);
        //If 'ESC' is pressed, break the loop
        if((char)c==27 ) break;      
    }
    cvDestroyAllWindows() ;
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. please do not use opencv's deprecated c-api, they moved to c++ years ago, and so should you.

Comment: c+/c++ that's not the problem. (you are using the *c* api, while you should not) if you see code using IplImages - avoid it ( specially here on SO.. )

Comment: I wanted to specify ranges to prevent false positives. In that case could i use if and case statments to declare ranges?

Comment: so there's a couple of colours, that you want to 'mask' out ?

Comment: Thats right im trying to detect fires so something like banana yellow would be a false positive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tl:dr;

use [bitwise-or](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-or) to combine binary masks,
[bitwise_and](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and) to apply them

```
cv::Mat mask1;
cv::inRange( hsv, cv::Scalar(20, 100, 100), cv::Scalar(30, 255, 255), mask1);
cv::Mat mask2;
cv::inRange( hsv, cv::Scalar(170,160,60),   cv::Scalar(180,255,256), mask2);
cv::Mat mask3;
cv::inRange( hsv, cv::Scalar(70,160,60),   cv::Scalar(90,255,256), mask3);

// combine them
cv::Mat mask_combined = mask1 | mask2 | mask3;

// now since our frame from the camera is bgr, we have to convert our mask to 3 channels:
cv::Mat mask_rgb;
cv::cvtColor( mask_combined, mask_rgb, CV_GRAY2BGR );

// finally, apply the mask to our image
frame = frame & mask_rgb;
```

Comment: Do i put it in the detection section?

Comment: probably. to be honest, i got no idea what you're trying to do. there's a couple of  operations in opencv, that take a binary mask (like the mask_combined above), you could use those. the example above is only one of many ways to go on

Comment: Should the masks go where i've added them if i want to add them to imgThresh?

Comment: no, you don't put this into your code at all. the above is c++, yours is c. so you'll either have to port your code to c++ (highly recommended anyway), or find a way to adapt the *idea* to your situation

Comment: Finally, found what I was looking for! BTW, this will work in python too.